# no such file to load -- soap4r -- why?

Tags: ruby, soap4r

I migrated to 1.8.7 Ruby and now I keep getting this error and it is driving me crazy.  I try installing it manually using gem install soap4r and also include it as a config.gem 'soap4r' and rake gem:install and still nothing....

It's blowing up on my heroku install too....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load it as

require 'soap4r' in your code

And make sure you installed soap4r with all the dependencies

here is a link for how to install it - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_web_services.htm

cheers

sameera

Comment: Hi, I do have require soap4r' I think that's what is causing it...what else can I do...?

Comment: Hi Angela. 

did your problem fixed ??. what do you mean by 'what else can I do'. If its not fixed could you pls post the log . Thanks 


cheers

sameera