# I keep getting a 'no such file to load' after installing the specific gem in Rails...why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, require

I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- soap4r
```

But I have already done a gem install soap4r...multiple times to make sure.

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

```
no such file to load -- soap4r
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
```

Comment: Offtopic hint: most people seem to have moved on to Savon (http://savon.rubiii.com/) now.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question several months ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572433/no-such-file-to-load-soap4r-why

Comment: yes, but the gem we're using the author insists on using soap4r

Comment: Do you have it listed as a config.gem? What happens when you `require "soap4r"` explicitly in your code?

Comment: Actually, if I recall correctly, you require 'soap/rpc/driver' or whatever module directly, not 'soap4r'. But it's been a few years since I've used it.

Comment: ah, if that's the case, then that would be the source of the problem....it's in a gem from a third party so I need to look into this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in a Rails application when I included the soap4r inside the config block in environment.rb.

I got rid of the error when I moved it to the top of the file, before the initializer block. 
This is what I have:

```
gem 'soap4r'
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'
```

This, inside the initializer block, gave me errors:

```
config.gem 'soap4r'
```