# Could not find soap4r (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-2.3.5, activeresource-2.3.5, activesupport-2.3.5, bundler-1.6.0, rack-1.0.1, rails-2.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I am using gem soap4R. When I run the application, it shows an error like:

> Could not find soap4r (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-2.3.5, actionpack-2.3.5, activerecord-2.3.5, activeresource-2.3.5, activesupport-2.3.5, bundler-1.6.0, rack-1.0.1, rails-2.3.5, rake-10.2.2] (Gem::Load Error)

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572433/no-such-file-to-load-soap4r-why

Comment: You duplicated a sentence, could you please elaborate it better?

Comment: Did you install the gem after including it in application?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include

> require 'soap4r'

in config/environment.rb
If you would like to use it with wsdldriver you will have use the following

> require 'soap/wsdlDriver'